# How to avoid the display of "0" values in Fields : SquareFootage and Price in the below screen shot?

Tags: apex, visualforce

When user performs any search. I want to display blank fields for Square Footage and Price Fields. But right now after user performs any search action the fields are auto-populated with "0" values i need them to be blank. How to do it?

[image: Search Page]

Kindly let me know how to add error messages on the below Apex method. If non-numeric values are entered in the Square Footage and Price Fields. Currently variables for the fields are String type.

```
public void  Search(){

   string searchquery= 'select name,Beds__c,Square_Footage__c,Initial_List_Price__c,Status__c from Condo__c where name!=null and Status__c in (\'Available\',\'Unsold\') ';


            if (beds >= '0')
               searchquery+= ' and Beds__c = '+beds+'';

            if (SFminimum > '0' && SFmaximum > '0') 
               searchquery+= ' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFminimum+' and Square_Footage__c <= '+SFmaximum+' ';

            if (ILPminimum >'0' && ILPmaximum > '0')
               searchquery += 'and Initial_List_Price__c >= '+ILPminimum+' and Initial_List_Price__c <= '+ILPmaximum+' ';


            if (beds >= '0' && SFminimum > '0' && SFmaximum > '0')
               searchquery+= ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFminimum+' and Square_Footage__c <= '+SFmaximum+' '; 

             if (beds >= '0' && ILPminimum > '0' && ILPmaximum > '0')

                 searchquery += 'and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Initial_List_Price__c >= '+ILPminimum+' and Initial_List_Price__c <= '+ILPmaximum+' ';

              if(beds >= '0' && SFminimum > '0' && SFmaximum > '0' && ILPminimum > '0' && ILPmaximum > '0')

                 searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFminimum+' and Square_Footage__c <= '+SFmaximum+' and Initial_List_Price__c >= '+ILPminimum+' and Initial_List_Price__c <= '+ILPmaximum+' ';

             if(beds >= '0' && SFminimum > '0')

                  searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c  >= '+SFminimum+' ';

              if(beds >= '0' && SFmaximum > '0')

                  searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Square_Footage__c  <= '+SFmaximum+' ';

              if(beds >= '0' && ILPminimum > '0')

                 searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Initial_List_Price__c  >= '+ILPminimum+' ';

               if(beds >= '0' && ILPmaximum > '0')

                 searchquery += ' and Beds__c = '+beds+' and Initial_List_Price__c  <= '+ILPmaximum+' ';

               if(SFminimum > '0')

                  searchquery += ' and Square_Footage__c >= '+SFminimum+' ';

                if(SFmaximum > '0')

                  searchquery += ' and Square_Footage__c  <= '+SFmaximum+' ';

                 if( ILPminimum > '0')

                   searchquery += ' and Initial_List_Price__c  >= '+ILPminimum+' ';

                 if(ILPmaximum > '0')

                 searchquery += ' and Initial_List_Price__c  <= '+ILPmaximum+' ';

     cond = Database.query(searchquery);


}
```

Comment: It is pretty easy. You can update your code with method, that make search string blank.

Comment: kindly elaborate your suggestion with an example.

Comment: instead of those inputs for decimals, make input for string and cast them to number on demand. That variables would be string type, and they have default value as empty string, while decimal or integer have default value as zero (0)